# Embedding Videos

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, youtube, adobe-flash

Files that I previously embedded into my powerpoints are no longer displaying and will not play.  They had been working previously in the week but not today.  I teach school and like the option to disable the videos at the end which is why I embed the object into the powerpoint.  It is just a black screen.  I have used the old embed code but it is no longer working.  Please, the other option to play the videos is not the best.

Comment: is your flash updated, also have you tried using more recent embed code?

Comment: Please add (to your question) the steps on how you embedded the YouTube videos. This will assist others in providing you with help.

Comment: aug2uag: Flash is updated. PowerPoint will only use the old embed code. @Jesse I selected the Embed option in YouTube. Selected old embed code (copied and pasted) and then went to the insert option in PPT, clicked on video from web (pasted code there), then clicked okay?

Comment: Have you checked if there are any changes to the videos on YouTube website? Personally I don't like embedding video to PPT the way you did. I would get the video of YouTube stored locally and then insert them into PPT.

Comment: I have checked to make sure. I read added the code again and it still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ask YouTube to copy the old embed code, and it should still work (at least in 2013).

On the video's web page, you can click the <kbd>Share</kbd> link, select **Embed**, then choose the tickbox `[x] Use old embed code`. The code it generates can be pasted into PowerPoint's **Insert Online Video** section

Ex:

```
<object width="420" height="315"><param name="movie"
value="http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0?hl=en_US&amp;version=3"></param>
<param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/oHg5SJYRHA0?hl=en_US&amp;version=3"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="420" height="315"
allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Comment: And how would one go about doing that? That seems like a very poor answer.

Comment: @Jesse I updated my answer. Sorry, I posted the answer from my phone, so I didn't have the exact wording

Comment: Hey, no problem! Thanks for updating the answer!

Comment: I have done all of the following options.  I know how to get the code.  It has just mysteriously stopped working in all of my ppt's since last week.

Comment: @LeighAnnFretwell Hmmm... This isn't working for me anymore either... I'm guessing YouTube did something to it

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the code specifying the version in the embed code - e.g. &version=3 . It is used twice in the embed code (see [Embedding Videos](https://superuser.com/questions/563191/embedding-videos)). This worked for me.

Comment: I will try this